# Qt-Creators youtubeview example won't show videos

Tags: qt, youtube

I am trying to embed YouTube videos in my Qt application using the QML `WebView`.

Both my application and the youtubeview example that comes with Qt-Creator manage to load the YouTube Player but won't play any video. The YouTube Player just displays the text "An error occurred. Please try again later.".I do not get any debug messages.

I am using Qt 5.4.1, Qt Creator 3.3.2 on Windows 7 with MinGW.

Comment: Which compiler? mingw or msvc?

Comment: @douyw I'm using mingw. Are you suggesting that this problem only exists in this very configuration?

Comment: Yes. I tried mingw before, without a success.